# Tailwind css unable to import style class

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-elements

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

Working with wordpress, laravel-mix, webpack, tailwind, postcss pakage. It has run without any error but default border, color, etc.. The classes of tailwind  are not import.

Comment: Have you tried :

`@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;`